# Espresso test NumberPicker

Tags: android, android-espresso, numberpicker

I'm using a numberPicker on my Android app, and I want to make some E2E tests to check it. I made a customView that holds the NumberPicker that looks like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/numberPicker_label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        style="@style/DatePickerLabel"
        android:paddingBottom="11dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/numberPicker_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:background="@drawable/number_picker_background"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/numberPicker_label">
        <NumberPicker
            android:id="@+id/numberPicker"
            style="@style/NumberPickerText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:theme="@style/NumberPickerText"/>
    </FrameLayout>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/numberPicker_button"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_info"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/numberPicker_layout"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/numberPicker_layout"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/numberPicker_layout"
        android:layout_marginEnd="7dp"  />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And to test it, I tried this:

```kotlin
protected fun numberPickerSelect(pickerId: Int, swipes: Int = 1) {
    val pickerView = onView(
        allOf(
            withId(R.id.numberPicker),
            isDescendantOfA(withId(pickerId))
        )
    )

    pickerView.perform(click())
    for (i in 0 until swipes) {
        pickerView.perform(swipeUp())
    }
}
```

but it throws me this error:

```
Error performing 'single click' on view 'Animations or transitions are enabled on the target device.
```

And if I remove the click() action and keep only the swipe, it throw the same error for swipeUp() too.
I need to say that animations are disabled on the device, and I'm pretty sure of that. Do you have any tips to test a numberPicker please ?

Thanks.